# Vector3 [] Unity not filling up with values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to read a JSON file in a Unity C# script and 
fill up a Vector3[] with the values.

The JSON file is as follows:

```
    "offsets": [
    [0.01,0.02,0.03],
    [0.04,0.05,0.06]
    ]
```

I am using the following code.

```
    SimpleJSON.JSONNode offset_node = SimpleJSON.JSON.Parse(filePath);
    Vector3[] offsets = new Vector3[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < offset_node["offsets"].Count; i++)
    {
        offsets[i] = new Vector3(offset_node["offsets"][i][0].AsFloat, offset_node["offsets"][i][1].AsFloat, offset_node["offsets"][i][2].AsFloat);
    }

    Debug.Log(offsets[0]);
    Debug.Log(offset_node["offsets"][0][0].AsFloat);
```

But Debug message shows:

```
    (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    0.01
```

Would anyone point out why is the first log message not showing up as
(0.01, 0.02, 0.03)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity's Vector3.ToString method is implicitly called and it rounds off the 
values in Vector3 to 1 decimal place to the right of the decimal point.

The following shows correct results.

```
    Debug.Log(offsets[0].ToString("F2")); // round off to 2 decimal places
```